# How many members $a$ in $\Bbb{Z}^*$ have a number $b$, $b^3 = a \pmod n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Given two prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $3$ does not divide $p-1$ nor $q-1$, and let $pq = n$.

How many numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$ (multiplicative group) are
equal to some $b^3$ where $b$ is a number ?

How does the fact that $3$ doesn't divide $(p-1)$ and $(q-1)$ help me find the answer ? All I know is that the size of $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$ does not divide by $3$ (because its size is $(p-q)(q-1)$) but how does it help me ?

Comment: Please use Mathjax

Comment: This equivalent to RSA with $e=3.$

Comment: @gammatester But in RSA we perform b^3 mod n = a and not b^3 = a mod n. How is it still RSA ?

Comment: Huh? Do you know what a congruence is? Your notation is mathematically not appropriate (although it is often used in cryptography and programming). 
Both of your "equations" mean that $b^3 - a$ is a multiple of n.

Comment: You are misunderstanding what $b^3\equiv a\pmod n$ means. It doesn't mean you're applying the modulus operation only to $a$. You could say you're applying it to both $a$ and $b^3$, but usually $a<n$ already.

Comment: I see, they really are the same. But how do i prove that there is only one ciphertext for the plaintext being encrypted ? I realize that otherwise we could decrypt the message wrongly but how to prove it formally ?

Comment: Assuming $p\ne q$ you have $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1).$ Since $\gcd(3, \varphi(n))=1$ you can define $d \equiv 3^{-1}\pmod {\varphi(n)}$ and apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Proofs_of_correctness

Comment: But how does "gcd(3,φ(n))=1" help us in showing that there is no other value for d ?  other than 3^-1

Comment: It does not help, because there are many possible decryption exponents, but all of them are equivalent (actually the RSA standard does not even use $\varphi(N)$ but the Carmichael function $\lambda(n),$ as shown in the Wiki article). Any non-zero multiple of $e^{-1}\pmod {\lambda}$ will work.

Comment: But here we show how to define the decryption, but maybe there is some other ciphertext that could be decrypted with the same d ? Why not ?

Comment: I suggest you take a closer look at the RSA introduction.

Comment: So the question is basically - how many ciphertexts in Zn* have sources b such that b^3 maps to that ciphertext. How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $3$ does not divide $p-1$, then $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection in $\mathbb Z_p$.